# Tried to write node index.js and i got error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was trying to run express node.js to "localhost:3000" but it always give me an error on my hyper terminal "unexpected token "=" 
And here is the code

```
//JS hint esversion:6

const = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", function(request , response) {
   response.send("hello");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("server started on prt 3000");

});
```

So whenever I run localhost:3000 the browser says This site can’t be reached

Comment: ```const = require("express");``` You forgot your variable name

Comment: const = require("express"); - this is a problem. const must have name in you case const express = require("express")

Comment: atleast you should see the syntax error in your console

Comment: Oh Guys thank you very much , you know i'm just a beginner ugh 
thanksss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the variable name after const

```
const express = require('express')
```

Answer (score -3):

I think u have 2 add bodyparser.

Comment: When answering a question, it's usually a good idea to look at the existing answers. The problem was solved six months ago with a solution that doesn't even resemble what you suggested. If the problem was a missing body parser then the problem would be that data was not available in a `post` request, but there isn't even a post request involved.